# How to find the Image control in GridView in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

How to find the Image Control Source in JavaScript. Image control is in ItemTemplate of GridView.

Please tell me how to find image control and its image siurce..

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gridViewTaxReturnDocuments" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gridViewTaxReturnDocuments_RowCommand"
    OnRowDataBound="gridViewTaxReturnDocuments_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
       <Columns>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Show To Client">
       <ControlStyle Font-Size="Larger" />
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgOnOff" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#isOnOff(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ShowToClient")))%>'
            OnClientClick='<%# "javascript:OnOffDocs(\""+ DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"RowID") +"\");return false;" %>'
            Height="16px" Width="28px" />
        </ItemTemplate>
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
     </asp:TemplateField>

      </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>

          function OnOffDocs(DocID) 
              {    
                     PageMethods.DocOnOff(DocID);
                    var gridViewTaxReturnDocuments = document.getElementById("gridViewTaxReturnDocuments").value;

                    var imgOnOff = gridViewTaxReturnDocuments.getElementById('imgOnOff');


                    if (imgOnOff.src.indexOf("switch-off.png") != -1) {
                        imgOnOff.src = "~/images/switch-on.png";
                    }
                    else if (imgOnOff.src.indexOf("switch-on.png") != -1) {
                        imgOnOff.src = "~/images/switch-off.png";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? do you need all the images from all rows? a specific one? the row clicked/selected? what is the point of this exercise? why are you trying to do this with client code?

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to look through all image tags on the page & check the id if it contains "imgOnOff" thus you identify your grid images.

What are you trying to do with the images exactly ?